# run_erl.c failing to start

Tags: erlang, run-erl

Normally, when my Erlang application starts via [`run_erl -daemon`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/run_erl.html), I see in the logs:

```
=====
===== LOGGING STARTED Mon May 16 14:39:11 UTC 2011
=====
Exec: /mware/erts-5.8.3/bin/erlexec -boot /mware/releases/1/gmcontroller -embedded -config /mware/etc/app.config -args_file /mware/etc/vm.args -- console
Root: /mware
heart_beat_kill_pid = 2302

Eshell V5.8.3  (abort with ^G)

(gmcontroller@127.0.0.1)1> 
===== ALIVE Mon May 16 14:54:34 UTC 2011

===== ALIVE Mon May 16 15:09:35 UTC 2011

===== ALIVE Mon May 16 15:24:36 UTC 2011

...
```

However, one time I've got

```
=====
===== LOGGING STARTED Mon May 16 19:48:14 UTC 2011
=====
Exec: /mware/erts-5.8.3/bin/erlexec -boot /mware/releases/1/gmcontroller -embedded -config /mware/etc/app.config -args_file /mware/etc/vm.args -- console
Root: /mware
heart_beat_kill_pid = 2217
```

with no prompt and no `===== ALIVE ...` messages until rebooting the computer. Are there any known causes for such behavior? My own suspicion is a problem with the file system.

Comment: Do/did you have old and invalid named pipes hanging around under /tmp/? It could be that restarting cleared your /tmp/ directory and that's why it works now.

Comment: Could you post it as an answer? I think it may be the reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do/did you have old and invalid named pipes hanging around under /tmp/? It could be that restarting cleared your /tmp/ directory and that's why it works now.